# How to link a bug created on Microsoft Test Manager to TFS?

Tags: tfs, mtm

I want to be able to see the bugs created on MTM in TFS without having to manually create them again. If anybody has any insight on how to automate this process please help.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific? Bugs created in MTM are already in TFS as that is the only place MTM stores them. What is your workflow?

Comment: I need to be able to link the bug back to the original PBI (work item) where it came from. MTM introduces the bug as a NEW bug without any links, I would like to know the work item that caused the bug.

Comment: If you are executing a test case when you create a bug it is linked to the Test Case. If the test case is liked to  PBI you can infer that relationship

Comment: I see, thanks. What i needed to know is if there is a way to attach the bug to the PBI so it's not it's own entity because we track defects a different way.

Comment: i guess what Im asking for is a way to automate that process so that we dont have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with MTM you are either executing Test Cases or doing Exploratory testing when you are creating bugs.

If you are executing test cases MTM will automatically associate any Bugs created with the Test Case in context. However, as your Test Case may test multiple PBI's the tool does not know which PBI is in context.

Note: I am not sure if, when using the 'Add Requirement' option to create a Test Suit that I linked to your PBI if the link to the PBI is created.

If you are doing exploratory testing, where you don't have a Test Case, then you can choose to "Explore a requirement". In this case both Bugs and Test Cases created are associated with the PBI in context.

If you run the reporting services Backlog Overview report you will see the number of tests passing and failing against PBI as this report follows the indirect links.